# Is there an inverse operation to 'ExpandSelection' (as a keyboard shortcut)?

Tags: front-end, keyboard

The keyboard shortcut associated to "ExpandSelection" (Ctrl+.) is really useful, but it is too easy to overshoot the desired selection. Is there an inverse operation to "ExpandSelection" in order to shrink/contract the selection.

By the way, I grepped `Mathematica/12.3/SystemFiles` looking for that kind of option, but I wasn't able to find anything relevant.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: For reference: The keyboard shortcut listing is [here](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/KeyboardShortcutListing.html)

Comment: Syed Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, that is an incomplete list.

Comment: Do you want the list to be more complete? or have you seen a more complete list?

Comment: I have seen a more complete list by grepping undocumented functions in the FrontEnd folder. However, in this case, I just want to confirm that I didn't miss the option to reverse "ExpandSelection"

Comment: I haven't seen such a `KeyEvent`. I use something like `Ctrl` + `->` to reverse my overshooting.

Comment: I think Ctrl + -> loses the selection. On the other hand, Ctrl + Shift + -> keeps the selection but it depends on the cursor placement and therefore, its behavior is different when the selection starts from the right or from the left.